# Extended Ascii doesn't work in console!

Tags: java, character-encoding, console, ascii, extended-ascii

For example
System.out.println("╚");
displays as a ?, same goes for System.out.println("\u255a");

Why doesn't this work? Stdout does indeed support these characters so I don't get it.

Comment: 1) "Extended Ascii" is utterly meaningless. 2) That’s obviously not your code. 3) What OS/terminal?

Comment: Command-prompt in windows. And Extended ascii is what it is called.

Comment: @jleedev tell OP how you really feel...

Comment: @DasWood by "Extended ASCII" are you referring to non-printing characters? Because, if that's the case, then yeah they won't display. Most consoles to my knowledge will only display in the 0-127 range but I've never really researched it so I could be wrong.

Comment: Since `System.out.println(╚);` isn't valid Java, please show the REAL code -- how did you generate the box-drawing character in code?

Comment: If I type it directly into the console it works but if I put it into a text file and 'type text.txt' I get garbage. I've seen this done before so formatting can be done. I wonder how.

Comment: @Jim Garrison that is what I have in my IDE, I tried that and \u255a, the box drawing set using character map set to DOS.

Comment: You can't have a naked unquoted character in `System.out.println()` -- please post the _actual_ code.

Comment: [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII): "The use of the term is sometimes criticized, because it can be mistakenly interpreted that the ASCII standard has been updated to include more than 128 characters or that the term unambiguously identifies a single encoding, both of which are untrue."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding). When Java’s default character encoding is not UTF-8 — as is the case, it seems, on Windows and OS X, but not Linux — then characters which fail to encode are converted to question marks. You can pass the correct switch (`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on some terminals, but I don’t have a Windows box in front of me) to the JVM’s command line, or you can set an environment variable. Portably determining what this should be might be impossible, but if you know that you will always run on the Win32 console, for example, you can choose a [Charset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to explicitly encode the characters before writing them to standard output, or you can directly write the bytes you need.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows command prompt uses old DOS OEM encodings by default. `System.out` uses the default system encoding, which will be a Windows "ANSI" encoding. However, `System.console()` detects the encoding of the console.

U+255A (╚) is more likely to be supported by the OEM codepages as these ranges were used for accented characters in Windows.

You can read more [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html), [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html), [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/java-unicode-on-windows-command-line.html) and [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html).

*Personally, I would avoid the `-Dfile.encoding` option with codepage 65001 as this produces unintended side-effects in both the console (batch files stop working) and Java ([bugs](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4163515)).*

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Windows, the console is not UTF-8 but UTF-16 which is the same native encoding that Java uses, therefore you should be able to print wide character strings directly.

I'm not a Java programmer but in the case of C you have to call `_setmode()` with the special mode `_O_U16TEXT` before printing UTF-16 will actually work.

If you want to print multibyte character strings instead you can set the Windows console to UTF-8 from the commandline with `chcp 65001` or programmatically from the Win32 API `SetConsoleOutputCP()` but beware a bug where `WriteFile()` returns the number of characters written instead of the number of bytes written as is documented. This bug causes UTF-8 on the Windows console to be corrupt from Perl, PHP and Ruby. I believe even MSVCRT even falls victim.

Good luck!